# Why does spark-shell fail to load a file with class with RDD imported?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use Spark 2.1.1 with Scala 2.11.8.

Inside `spark-shell` I use `:load` command to load a class that has methods with RDDs.

When I try to load the class I get the following compilation error:

> error: not found: type RDD

Why? I've got the import statement.

[image]

This is the code I'm working with

[image: image1]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Also, try to post your code/errors as a snippet instead of images.

Comment: Check and make sure the spark dependencies are provided mainly spark_core dependency added in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Does the class path come into play when working in spark-shell?

Comment: Yes, but not for this issue since the classes belong to Spark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems a *feature* of `:load` in `spark-shell`. A solution is to move `import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` (no dot and underscore) to your class definition.

This seems not specific to the `RDD` class but any classes imported. It won't work unless the `import` statement is defined inside the class itself.

With that said, the following won't work due to import being outside the class.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
class Hello {
  def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
}

scala> :load hello.scala
Loading hello.scala...
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
<console>:12: error: not found: type RDD
         def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
                                    ^
<console>:12: error: not found: type RDD
         def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
                      ^
```

You can see what happens under the covers using `-v` flag of `:load`.

```
scala> :load -v hello.scala
Loading hello.scala...

scala>

scala> import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

scala> class Hello {
     |   def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
     | }
<console>:12: error: not found: type RDD
         def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
                                    ^
<console>:12: error: not found: type RDD
         def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
                      ^
```

That led me to *guess* that having the import inside the class definition could help. And it did! (to my great surprise)

```
class Hello {
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
}

scala> :load -v hello.scala
Loading hello.scala...

scala> class Hello {
     |   import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
     |   def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
     | }
defined class Hello
```

You could also use `:paste` command to paste the class to `spark-shell`. There's the so-called raw mode when you could define classes in their own package.

```
package mypackage

class Hello {
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
}

scala> :load -v hello.scala
Loading hello.scala...

scala> package mypackage
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
package mypackage
^

scala>

scala> class Hello {
     |   import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
     |   def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
     | }
defined class Hello

scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package mypackage

class Hello {
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  def get(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = rdd
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

Comment: Also note, this is not specific just to the RDD class but for any classes being imported, it won't work unless the import package has been defined INSIDE the class itself. But can multiple classes be imported for multiple definitions inside a class??

Comment: Didn't know. Just learnt it from you! Thanks. As to multiple classes, think it's acceptable but needs testing as `:load` seems to put additional rules on the syntax (as we've just learnt).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in spark-shell, please refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22393 and was fixed in spark 2.3.0. Please use spark 2.3.0(or later) or use the method suggested by @Jacek Laskowski